# How to pass props to another component with <Link> in React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm using an array to display set of search results and on clicking one item, I want to pass the item as props, and not as params.

Here is my code:

```
{ this.props.results.map((result) => {              //Fetching Each Element
                return (
                    <li key={ result._source.file_name }>
                        <Link to={{pathname: '/photo/' + result._source.file_name + '/' + result._source.keywords, state: { modal: true }}}>
                            <img src={'/photos/' + result._source.file_name} className="image grow-shadow" alt="Search Result" />
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                ) }) }
```

I want to pass `key={result._source.keywords}` as props and not as params in route like

`<Route path='/photo/:id/:keyw' component={Single} />`

This will make URL look ugly.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `state`? ie `<Link to={{pathname: '/photo/:id', state: {keyw: result._source.keywords}}></Link>`

Comment: and how will I use in my <Single /> Component @gurch101 ?

Comment: Are there any reasons why you would not want to pass it via params?

Comment: This will make URL look Ugly. @ickyrr as there are many keywords

Comment: 1. Do you use redux?
2. So, to clarify, in the Route you don't want to have the keywords in the URL, but you would like to get them through the props?

Comment: 1. No, @croraf, i'm not using Redux.
2. Yes I want the keywords not to go in the URL, and I want it to go through props.

Comment: What is your folder structure (show part where you have Route, routed component that you call Single, and component from question)?
For example:
src/componentWithLink, src/route, src/routeComponent

Answer (score 0):

The link can be structured as follows:

`<Link to={{pathname: '/photo/:id', state: {keyw: result._source.keywords}}></Link>`

In the component, you can access the state as follows:

`this.props.location.state.keyw`

Passing state through the Link itself uses the HTML5 history state object which should be persisted across refreshes.